# Whats' wrong with the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary, british-english

> One thing that despise me is when people cannot look me in eye.

I believe that the statement is grammatically wrong since we are using passive voice in the sentence so it should be 'despises' instead of despise . 
Moreover , I believe the sentence doesn't make any sense. Its' hard for me to justify since I am not a native speaker  of English language .

Comment: Hi, Dave. Can you be more specific? Where do you think there is a problem, or what is it that you aren't sure about in the sentence? General proofreading requests ("are there any mistakes in this text?") are off-topic for this site per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Hi aedia.I hope you can understand that I am new to the website.

Comment: The sentence as given is grammatically incorrect. The subject of "despise" is "one thing". As "one thing" is singular the verb should also be singular, "despises". That change would make it grammatically correct but rather non-sensical. "Despise" means "hate", so you would then be saying that "one thing that hates me ..." But it's not the thing that hates you; it's you that hates the thing. So you could either take Mr Hunting's suggestion, "One thing that I despise ...", or choose a word that has the "opposite direction" of disklike, e.g. "One thing that annoys me is ..."